# How to access specific cells of a csvfile in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following `CSV` file:

```
Sample,Forward,Reverse
Micro1,EF30159600_EF30159600,EF30159601_EF30159601
Micro2,EF30159603_EF30159603,EF30159604_EF30159604
PseudaA,EF30159607_EF30159607,EF30159608_EF30159608
```

and the following piece of code:

```py
#!/miniconda/bin/python
import csv

with open("/home/lamma/local-blast/scripts/test.csv", 'r') as file:
    samples = csv.reader(file)
    for row in samples:
        print(row[1])
```

and I want to be able to for a start print one single row such as:

```
Micro2,EF30159603_EF30159603,EF30159604_EF30159604
```

instead of :

```
Sample
Micro1
Micro2
PseudaA
```

which is currently happening.

But I also then want to be able to iterate over the `CSV` file and extract each column so just `EF30159603_EF30159603` for example. I wish to do this as I need use the values in columns 2 and 3 which are file names, and then rename those files with the value in column 1.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Edit:

Adding the final code I have come to after help from @accdias

```
with open(args.csv, 'r') as file:
    samples = csv.reader(file)
    for row in list(samples)[1:]:
        os.rename(args.path + '/' + row[1] + '.seq', args.path + '/' + row[0] + '_1.fasta')
        os.rename(args.path + '/' + row[2] + '.seq', args.path + '/' + row[0] + '_2.fasta')
```

Comment: Change `print(row[1])` to `print(*row)`.

Comment: _print_ attaches a "\n" seperator automatically. If you want to print single row, just __print(row)__

Comment: Ahh okay so `for X in Y`in python functions similar to in R where X would become a numberic value of whatever part of Y the loop is currently on?

Comment: `row` in your code will give you one row at a time from the `CSV` file (header is going to be the first one). On each `row` we will get columns by its indexes, starting at `0` so, for your example `CSV`, `row[0]`, `row[1]`, `row[2]` will be mapped to `Sample`, `Forward`, and `Reverse` columns, respectively.

Comment: Ah okay this makes sense :) How can I ommit certain rows? As now I am calling the header row which I have no need for anymore so how would I replicated `row[2:4]` in R?

Comment: To skip the header row change your `for loop` into `for row in samples[1:]:`.

Comment: If you want to print the entire ``row``, why do you explicitly print only ``row[1]``? Note that ``row[1]`` should print the ``Forward``, ``EF30159600_EF30159600``, ... column, but your code shows the prior column -- is what you show the actual data, code and output you have?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no it is not the exact just a replica of what I get vs what I want

Comment: @accdias chaging the for loop to `for row in samples[1:]:` produes the error `TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable`. Any idea why?

Comment: My bad. Change the for loop into `for row in list(samples)[1:]:` or leave it as the way you had in your original code and add a line with `next(samples)` right before you start the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much @accdias. This works perfectly now :)

Comment: Check my answer. I tried to summarize all my comments there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing my comments, you can do something like this to iterate over the rows in you `CSV` file in a more intuitive way:

```py
import csv

csvfile = '/home/lamma/local-blast/scripts/test.csv'

with open(csvfile) as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)

    headers = next(rows)

    for sample, forward, reverse in rows:
        # do something with sample, forward, and reverse
        # rinse and repeat
```

Here is an alternative of your updated code using `pathlib` and `f-strings` (as I said in my comment, it requires Python 3.6+):

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path

# I'm assuming you are processing args somewhere else
# in your code
path = Path(args.path)
csvfile = Path(args.csv)

with csvfile.open() as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)

    headers = next(rows)

    # avoid using generic indexed elements of rows
    # for clarity in the code
    for sample, forward, reverse in rows:
        # process forward sample file
        seq = path / f'{forward}.seq'
        fasta = path / f'{sample}_1.fasta'

        if seq.exists():
            seq.rename(fasta)

        # process reverse sample file
        seq = path / f'{reverse}.seq'
        fasta = path / f'{sample}_2.fasta'

        if seq.exists():
            seq.rename(fasta)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: All looks good :) I edited my question to include the final code I came to also.

Comment: In the update you posted I see you are using `os` to compose file names and rename them. If you are on Python 3.4+, consider using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and if you are on Python 3.6+, consider also using [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). Your code will be a lot cleaner if you do that and I can show a sample if you want.

Comment: Yes please that would be very beneficial. I am running on Python 3.6.7 :)

Comment: @Lamma, done. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

```
#!/miniconda/bin/python
import csv
with open("/home/lamma/local-blast/scripts/test.csv", 'r') as file:
    samples = csv.DictReader(file)
    for idx, row in enumerate(samples):
        print (*row.values(), sep="\t")
        print("Row", idx, "Forward: ", row["Forward"])
        print("Row", idx, "Reverse: ", row["Reverse"])
        # you can do anything with this row's vlaues
```

The reader convert each row into Ordered dict, so you can access the vlaues with their names.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be working with data files frequently, I'd recommend using the `pandas` library. With `pandas`, you can do something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/home/lamma/local-blast/scripts/test.csv')
# access row by index
row = df.iloc[1]
# convert the pandas series to a list
row_list = row.tolist()
# access cell by index
cell = df.iloc[1, 1]
```

In general, it makes working with tabular data extremely easy.

Check out the docs for [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

You can also easily select columns as lists too:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/home/lamma/local-blast/scripts/test.csv')

# get the columns as lists
samples = df['Sample'].tolist()
forward = df['Forward'].tolist()
reverse = df['Reverse'].tolist()
```